# Determine when default attributes are changed in layout file

Tags: android, android-widget, android-resources

In Android, you can specify the attributes for widgets in layout files. Some attributes are required while others are optional. I am creating a custom control. The user can set the background color for the control using the standard background attribute:

```
android:background="@color/red"
```

What I need to know though is when this attribute has been set in the layout. If the user doesn't set the background color, my widget will use a default color rather than the view's own default color.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

ColorDrawable vColor = (ColorDrawable) getBackground();

if the `android:background="@color/red"` is not in the layout file, vColor will return null. While this solution works for an attribute like background, I am curious how this would work for other attributes. It assumes that there is an equivalent API that returns null but I'm not certain that is the case for all attributes.